# ASP.Net API running on Windows Azure websites

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-app-service

I have an MVC project in Visual Studio 2012 RC which hosts an MVC web site and an ASP.NET API.  I use routes to delegate the request to the correct controller.

On my local development machine both the website and api work fine.  However when I push the change to Azure websites the website works, but the ASP.NET web api returns HTTP 500 errors.

The base site is: http://salaahtime.azurewebsites.net
One of the web site pages is http://salaahtime.azurewebsites.net/website/login

An example use of the API is http://salaahtime.azurewebsites.net/api/salaahtime/testestablishment/2012/1

However this returns HTTP 500.

I have

- Updated my project to use .net 4.0.  By default it is set to .net 4.5 which does not work with Azure websites

  - Removed Entity Framework 5.0 reference which only works with .net 4.5

Any ideas why the api would not work in Azure websites?

Comment: Please put some code about API you are using in your code and how you are using it to route to delegate the request to the correct controller. I think it is your code which seems to work incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

There is a known issue when backing a project down from 4.5 to 4.0 using the RC release of Visual Studio 2012. I know this will be slightly painful to hear, but you'll be better off creating a new project and setting the project's framework version to 4 rather than 4.5. This is an issue that should be fixed prior to the product's release.

Hope this helps. Trust me, we know of it and in our own development work have had to re-create projects using the 4 framework.

Also - the 4.5 framework will be supported in Windows Azure Web Sites once the 4.5 framework has been officially released.

Comment: Did you mean the RTM Release ;-) ? Is there currently a expected date for .net 4.5 on Azure WebsiteS?

Comment: If you need .Net 4.5 support on Azure, please vote for it on the UserVoice site: http://www.mygreatwindowsazureidea.com/forums/34192-windows-azure-feature-voting/suggestions/2598170-iis8-and-asp-net-4-5-support-in-azure-platform

Answer (score 0):

Please try to turn off custom error (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx), which may give more detailed information. If you’re working with a database, make sure you’ve updated the connection string to use Windows Azure SQL Database instead of a local database. There is also a possibility that Web API is not stood by web sites. The name web sites indicate it is used to build web sites, not web platforms. Web sites have limited features compared to web roles and virtual machines. If that’s the case, please use a web role or a virtual machine.

Best Regards,

Ming Xu.